# django substitute dictionary with a faster JSON serializer

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I'm using Django raw queryset to select data from database.

I will need a translation (by using ugettext) on a field before I return this json serialized data to django rest_framework as an API

However I'm having optimization issue as this I found out it takes quite a while to manually append dictionary to a list especially if I have a lot of database rows.

After some searching i found a library  [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) that claims can serialize JSON faster. However I'm struggling to use this as I need this raw query to return **translated** name of a field (fruits)

Anyone have any idea how to replace this dictionary method with other faster method to serialize JSON data?

```
all_fruits = []
activate ("en")

raw_query = MyObject.objects.raw(" select id, fruits from my_table ")

for each_name in raw_query:
    json_obj = dict( id = each_name.id,
                     fruits= ugettext(each_name.fruits)
                   )
    all_fruits.append(json_obj)
```

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks at hand? For me the main problem is `ugettext()` call.

Comment: I use print state to find where part of the program is time consuming, and this "dictionary" part is causing the delay. Any work around for "ugettext" ?

Comment: try to test performance with and without `ugettext`. if it is the problem then you may add another column and pretranslate it. if not - it might help if you post your models and query + maybe sample data

Comment: I tried without ugettext. Its about the same speed

Answer (score 0):

*It's better to avoid raw SQL only when you really have no other Solution, **Django QuerySet** provide very great and full-featured API for database query, the following solution could fit your needs:*

```
all_fruits = []
activate ("en")

my_object_list = MyObject.objects.all()

for obj in my_object_list.values():
    all_fruits.append({"id":obj.id, "fruits" : ugettext(obj.fruits)})
```

Comment: I'm running a complicated sql query that combines many tables and calculate distance based on lat and lng coordinates, the above code is only a simplified example

Comment: Check [Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/), it's destined to complex queries